# Java inheritance how to take user input and pass it to sub-sub class?

Tags: java, inheritance, user-input, shapes

This is my first ever post here so bear with me please! I have a program that I need to write. Here are the instructions: create a class called areaExcersice in that class you will have a super class called shapes then below it twoDimensionalShapes followed by sub sub class circle and square under the twoDimensionalShapes. In circle extends twoDimensionalShapes, I will pass the user input of radius for example:

```
System.out.print("what is the radius");
```

and then

```
radius = input.nextDouble()
```

already know how to create and assign classes in a hierarchy system, however, I have no idea how I'm gonna call my circle class under the twiDimensionalShapes. I have to create an if statement so the user can select which shape to choose so something like this "press 1 for circle or 2 for square" and on my

```
if(user_input == 1){
```

Here is my question how would I call circle class under twodDimensionalShapes to find the area and pass on radius? Thanks this is all i need to know please if you can just point me out in the good direction i already have created an instance for ex

```
Circle c = new Circle
```

Then in my if statement i would do `c.getArea()` but then where would I put my radius that is asked from the user?

Comment: I think that you're going to want to post more code and more details of your problem. Please note that your question is a tad on the sloppy side with some spelling and capitalization errors, and you will want to strive to be as accurate as possible with your questions and your code. The Java compiler is unforgiving and strict, and so you must be as well.

Comment: Perhaps you want something like, `TwoDimensionalShape twoDShape = new Circle(someRadius);`, and then call `twoDShape.getArea()`, but I'm not yet really sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my pet peeves with these kinds of projects is they explicitly ask you to create classes when there is no need for them.  This only confuses students who can't figure out why they're doing something because there really isn't a reason to do it.  You've given no reason to have a Shape class.  In the real world I'd take that as an excuse to get rid of it.  Since you're required to have one I'm inventing a reason for it to exist: color.  This way you can see what Shape might be useful for.  If you say "I don't need color" I say "you don't need Shape".  See how that works?

I'm using a dirty little trick here called static inner classes so this all works in one file.  If you copy this at least take the static of the classes and move them into their own files.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AreaExcersice {

    public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Choose 1 for circle or 2 for square:");
        int userInput = Integer.parseInt( input.nextLine() );

        TwoDimensionalShape twoDShape = null; 
        if (userInput == 1) {
            System.out.println("Enter a radius for circle:");
            int radius = Integer.parseInt( input.nextLine() );    

            twoDShape = new Circle("Blue", radius, radius, radius);
        } else if (userInput == 2) {
            System.out.println("Enter a length for the sides of the square");
            int side = Integer.parseInt( input.nextLine() );    

            twoDShape = new Rectange("Green", 0, 0, side, side);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid input.");
        }

        if (twoDShape != null) {
            System.out.println( twoDShape.toString() );        
        }
    }

    public static abstract class Shape {
        String color;
        public Shape(String color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

        public abstract String toString();
    }

    public static abstract class TwoDimensionalShape extends Shape {
        int x;
        int y;
        public TwoDimensionalShape(String color, int x, int y) {
            super(color);
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
        public abstract double getArea();
    }

    public static class Circle extends TwoDimensionalShape {
        int radius;
        public Circle(String color, int x, int y, int radius) {
            super(color, x, y);
            this.radius = radius;            
        }
        @Override
        public double getArea() {
            return Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return color + " circle at " + x + ", " + y + " with radius " + 
                radius + " and area of " + getArea();
        }
    }

    public static class Rectange extends TwoDimensionalShape {
        int height;
        int width;
        public Rectange(String color, int x, int y, int height, int width) {
            super(color, x, y);
            this.height = height;
            this.width = width;
        }
        @Override
        public double getArea() {
            return width * height;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return color + " rectange at " + x + ", " + y + " with height " + 
                height + ", width " + width + " and area of " + getArea();
        }
    }
}
```

Displays:

```
Choose 1 for circle or 2 for square:
1
Enter a radius for circle:
20
Blue circle at 20, 20 with radius 20 and area of 1256.6370614359173
```

This maybe overkill but it should be clearly showing you what an inheritance structure can do for you.  Each class only has implementation code particular to it.  Nothing is duplicated.  Instead it's shared.  Any questions?

Comment: Thanks so much guys! i have not yet covered abstract classes but i figured it out on my own thanks to your explicit examples! i understand the concepts but when i saw the complicated code something clicked within me and alas! i saw the light!

Comment: Glad we helped.  Another way you can show your appreciation is in the upper left corner of these answers.  Upvote those you think deserve it and choose one to accept.  It's how we get our little gold star stickers.

Answer (score 0):

You could move anything that's common amongst all of your Shape or TwoDimensionalShape subclasses so that they can be referenced generically:

```
public abstract class Shape<T extends TwoDimensionalShape> {
    public abstract String getName(); // Get the name of the shape for display purposes
    public abstract double getArea(); // Get the surface area of this Shape
}

public abstract class TwoDimensionalShape<T extends TwoDimensionalShape> extends Shape<T> {
    private double area = 0;
    public double getArea() {
        return this.area;
    }
    protected void setArea(double area) {
        this.area = area;
    }
}

public class Circle extends TwoDimensionalShape<Circle> {
    public Circle ( double radius ) {
        setArea( Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2) );
    }
    public String getName() {
        return "Circle";
    }
}

public class Square extends TwoDimensionalShape<Square> {
    public Square ( double width, double height ) {
        setArea( width * height );
    }
    public String getName() {
        return "Square";
    }
}
```

Comment: These calculations should be done in getters not setters so were not forced to make the shapes immutable.  The generics would be a nice touch if they were used for anything.

Answer (score 0):

So the point of having TwoDimensionalShapes is a bit obscure, but we can guess that it defines methods like "getArea()" without implementing them.  Each class that extends TwoDimensionalShapes has to implement its own area calculation.

I don't think things like "setArea(double area)" are very useful; areas are not so difficult to calculate that we need to store them, and storing them causes other problems.

So we end up with something like these:

```
public TwoDShape extends Shape // I have no use for Shape in this example...
{
  public double getArea();  // this is an abstract method, hope you've covered those.
}

public Circle extends TwoDShape
{
  private double radius;
  public Cirlcle(double givenRadius) { radius = givenRadius; }

  public double getArea() { return PI*radius*radius; }
}
```

I've left out a great deal.  The getArea() should insure the radius is not 0 and do something like throw an exception if it is, for instance.

Now, to use this, you might have:

```
public class Main
{
  public static void main(String ... arguments)
  {
    Circle c = new Circle(4.0);
    System.out.println("Radius of 4 gives area of " + c.getArea(); 
  }
}
```

Now, I'll leave Square to you to do, it will be quite similar to Circle.  Let us know how it goes.  After you've done Square, you'll be able to do something like:

```
public Main
{
  public static void main(String ... arguments)
  { 
    Shape[] shapes = new Shape[3];
    shapes[0] = new Circle(4.0);
    shapes[1] = new Square(5.0);
    shapes[2] = new Square(6.0);
    for (shape : shapes)
    {
      System.out.println("Area is " + shape.getArea());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! You guys are all awesome!! I have not yet covered abstract classes but your explicit code showed me the way! Something clicked on me and alas! i saw the light beaming across the room! I idolize you programmers as well as admire you because someday i will become a professional just like you guys. I am striving to achieve deep knowledge within the programming field and this is just the start. Again thank you so much for clearing my head and pointing me in the right direction! It feels so good to complete a program on your own and have it output correctly and thanks Stack Overflow and all its respective members!I am a noob and first time posting here so i might get down voted for answering in an incorrect format.